# How to get JVM use diffrent version of jars required in application

Tags: java, spring, dependency-management

In application where  it requires Spring 2.0 jar and wants to interface with webservice but client.jar provided by webservice host require spring3.0 jar.. so is there any way to implement both versions of Spring?